# Clustering product searches into products

Tags: clustering

I've been tasked with clustering searches from our website into the different searches for the same product. e.g. such different searches for the same product may be "product name" / "product name 1st release" / "product name 1995" / "product name 2004" / "prodct name" (mis-spelling intended) / "author 1995 part-of-product-name" and so on.

I seem to have a million or so searches like this for various products with various search strings. I don't have category or any other grouping data.

How can I cluster these search strings into their respective products / items with as minimum input from me as possible?